# Is it possible to upload multiple files using module "multiparty" in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, node-modules, multifile-uploader

Was using multiparty node module in node app  for uploading a single file. Now, I want to upload multiple files using the same multiparty module.I googled but could not find any solution and ended up finding 'multer' module in the [link](https://codeforgeek.com/2016/01/multiple-file-upload-node-js/) which is giving some issue with the existing application. So, is there any way to achieve uploading of file using 'multiparty' ?

Answer (score 2):

After many failed attempts and experimentation got the answer, have sent a form object to the server from the client. Just have a check of the below code on the server side

```
app.post('/multiFileUpload', function(req, res) {

        var singleFile;     
        var form = new multiparty.Form();

       form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){    
          var fileArry=files.uploadFiles;                   
                    if(fileArry == null ){
                        res.send('No files found to upload.');
                            return; 
                    }

                        for(i=0; i<fileArry.length; i++)
                        {  
                            newPath='./uploads/';
                            singleFile=fileArry[i];
                            newPath+=singleFile.originalFilename;
                            readAndWriteFile(singleFile,newPath);                       
                        }
                        res.send("File uploaded to: " + newPath);
                });

    });

     function readAndWriteFile(singleFile , newPath){

        fs.readFile(singleFile.path, (err, data)=>{
            fs.writeFile(newPath, data, (err)=>{                                                                                                                
                    console.log("File uploaded to  :"+newPath);
                });
        });
    }
```

Comment: I did the very same than you and did just upload only the last file. The only difference was that I did the readFile and fs.writeFile inside the For. I don't know why it wasn't working. Anywa thanx! :D @Worker

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [request](https://github.com/request/request) module. It will help you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @David,  an example using the same would be more helpful.